# why does typescript not discriminate a base type from its intersection types

Tags: typescript, intersection-types

This question might already be answered somewhere in [this somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395823/why-does-typescript-not-simplify-the-intersection-of-a-type-and-one-of-its-super), however the example code and explanations are a very verbose and I can't really seem to distill it down the useful parts.

I am hoping someone can provide an explanation as to why the following code doesn't produce a type error on the indicated line. Is there any utility type I can use which would produce the result I want?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgWQghcDm0C8UDeUAZgPYkBcUCwATgJYB2mUAvgLABQnokUAUiQBGqdFlyxEKNBmxQAZASiC4NSgwCuAW0EQarTpwDGJBtShgaJQ9PhIoeABSaEmSramjsASnsA+AuxcHMamwOaW1ugCgvZQTi6U0SIyED44-vicUFAA9DlQAJJQEAAekIZhwAAWdAhQDKVhADaM0MAkxTSWNFnhVjaS8ZheANy9eVAAKjV1FiQAJuqRUNXQut2FUHCaUFUkYIzMpD0c2XORCO4OhKQUUADk1DT3ADRKKpQAjABMAMwALKxRpxAkA)

```
type BaseMessage = { foo: string }

type JobMessage = BaseMessage & { bar: number }

const processBase = (msg: BaseMessage) => {}

const processJob = (msg: JobMessage) => {
  // I expect this next line to error
  processBase(msg);
  // This produces the error I am hoping for
  processBase({ foo: 'str', bar: 1234 });
}
```

Comment: `processBase` doesn't care if you provided extra properties. After all, it's not supposed to use them...

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with intersections but with [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), which only get triggered for object literals (and only in certain contexts). Since `msg` is not an object literal, excess property checks don't occur.

Comment: Well, you could add a check like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkkA2W), but it will be really annoying to work with `msg` in the body of `processBase`.

Comment: The link should be updated now. 

@caTS - I get that `processBase` doesn't use the extra properties, but in the second invocation in the example code, I pass extra properties and I get the type error I want: "bar does not exist on BaseMessage".

Comment: _Not_ erroring on the excess properties is awesome, BTW. It's really common to define only what a function cares about and then pass in something bigger that conforms to that. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJxgXhgbxgSwCYBcMA5AigLQCMATAMzEA0MUAngA6JGlLKMxgBDALacSAMRAgYAWWAAhAbxgBfALAAoUJFgAjSQGt0WXIRJ6Q+8gBYArADY+rDl3P7HOKABtRxaSB0sMAAiOMBuKhoaAGZwYMBQOOAweIjeUIgASoigyHgAFMjZILlE2PhE0Mg4YADmTE6ildU1KgCUWBowMAD03ck6AHQ1iFAAKgI63nkNrQMpaYh5+O29MMUwECAiUAAWzQMaauoa8yOZRbl5ZMgrfVHViCepZ1k5+a63MPdgiEA

Comment: @jcalz - can you post your explanation in an answer, I'll accept it. Also, is it possible to have a utility which can help achieve what I'm needing? If not, please say so in your answer.

Comment: Using the `Exactly` helper type from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647392/extend-and-only-specify-known-properties) gives you [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6ndw), but it's always possible to circumvent with enough ingenuity on the part of the determined caller.  You should probably just make sure that your `processBase()` *does not care* about excess properties

Comment: @jcalz - the last example you provided is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. I feel like the links you provided are still very verbose and over-indulged. I'm just trying to show a distilled problem/solution. Can you please provide your playground code as an answer - it makes it very easy to see the solution and it's caveats (unlike the other solutions you reference).

Comment: ". I feel like the links you provided are still very verbose and over-indulged" Well since I wrote those you're probably going to get more of the same if you ask me for it.  Maybe someone else can help you?  This question is already closed as a duplicate though, so feel free to write up an answer of your own to one or more of those questions if you feel the answers are too meandering.