# Merging Fields of an intersection type into a single object type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How can I get all the fields of a Typescript intersection type into a single object type?

for example

```
type A = { foo: string }
type B = { fizz: number }
type C = { bar: boolean }
type D = { buzz: null | string }

type All = A & B & C & D
```

the resulting type for `All` becomes

```
{ foo: string } & { fizz: number } & { bar: boolean } & { buzz: null | string }
```

and this isn't very readable especially when trying to figure out a ts error message.

I tried this solution after reading the ts docs in hope of creating a new object type that contains all the fields from `T` and `U`

```
type Merge<T, U> = {
    [P in (keyof T | keyof U)]: P extends keyof T
        ? T[P]
        : P extends keyof U
          ? U[P]
          : never;
}
```

This didn't solve my problem (give me readability) because using this, the type of `All` is now displayed as

```
Merge<Merge<Merge<A, B>, C>, D>

// or as 
Merge<Merge<Merge<{ foo: string }, { fizz: number }>, { bar: boolean }>, { buzz: null | string }>
```

What I want is a case where calling `Merge<A, B>` produces

```
{
  foo: string
  fizz: number
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: *Functionally*, the type already acts exactly as you want. It appears the TS designers *prefer* to show you the original types that go into the intersection rather than the computed reduction, but that shouldn't change *how the type actually works*.

Comment: Somewhat [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72395823/15498)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. it does behave as I would expect.
The reason I want this is because i'm using this in building a library, and I want to provide meaningful and readable types for users of the library. Also, when ts shows an error, the error is difficult to read, even for me.